# Why are my pictures in a beamer template grey?

Tags: beamer, color

I am using the theme in http://melmorabity.fedorapeople.org/latex/beamer/old/beamer-goddard/beamer-goddard-0.1.tar.bz2

My problem is when I insert a picture, my picture colors are all grey, I would like to insert my pictures and preserve their colors

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this hold for *any* picture, or specific file formats? JPG, PDF, ...?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but  I am sorry i don't know what means by MWE I am very native with beamer

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes for picture .png end .jpg. if you have time please try to insert a picture and tell me what's your result. I have install MWE and I insert the  \begin{frame} \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100bp} \end{frame} as it is but I have noting .thanks for reding my message

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a local installation of packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for my problem, it's because I have installed a few days ago some packages that cause this problem. In addition, to get my pdf document I have used LaTex-PS-PDF and not directly LaTex-PDF.